# Unable to open file from Windows NTFS partition

Tags: mount, windows-10, ntfs

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04LTS
I mounted Windows NTFS partition,
I can see all files but can not open file like .jpg, .pdf & .mp4
Anyone can assist me?
[screen capture as per attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6IRH.png)

Comment: How is this drive mounted? If through fstab it looks like a permissions issue. If auto mounted by the OS, it might be you need to mount via fstab.

Comment: I mount manually from file manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the arrows on these icons mean that they represent symlinks, or maybe placeholders from onedrive, considering the OneDrive-few path component. So try to locate the real file.

Also try detailed list view, or however it is called in your file manager. That may tell you the location that the symlink points to.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Now I know why is error because OneDrive-few from Windows side has security privileges. Another files outside OneDrive-few is able to read by Linux. [OneDrive] https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhgUW7cZIEzBkeN0BVZ0fertzlAA7g?e=HzPR5H